# executing SPI command in function in under 1ms - 8051

Tags: microcontroller, boolean-logic, bit, spi, 8051

Currently I have an AT89C2051 microcontroller hooked up to an ISD soundchip through a multiplexer-demultiplexer setup. I have other things too but my focus is making sound execute as fast as possible. Currently the speed of the chip is 3.6Mhz since another microcontroller is driving this microcontroller.

Based on documentation and experimentation, The sound chip requires 7 bytes to be sent to it in order for me to make it play sound between any two ranges of memory. The part that takes the time is transmitting the seven bytes.

This is the code I have so far that works:

```
  FLUSH bit P3.7            ;Low=enable data reception
  ENXMIT bit P3.5           ;High=Enable data transmission
  GLOBALCLK bit P3.1        ;TXD: clock (connects to soundcard clock)
  GLOBALDAT bit P3.0        ;RXD: I/O data line (connects to MISO and MOSI)

  C_SND2 = address of soundcard 2
  C_SND = address of soundcard 1

  O_SND:
      setb FLUSH            ;disable reception
      clr ENXMIT            ;disable transmission
      mov R7,A              ;Parameter in: Accumulator = # bytes to transfer out. 
      mov A,#C_SND2         ;A=address of soundcard 2
      mov R6,#C_SND         ;R6=address of soundcard 1
      jnb SS,nc1            ;Parameter in: SS = soundcard to use.
          xch A,R6          ;Switch A + R6 if other soundcard is wanted.
      nc1:
                          ;NOTE: soundcard Slave select lines are connected together through an inverter.
      mov P1,R6            ;Enable wrong soundcard (to disable the correct one)
      mov R0,#BUFOUT       ;Set data space pointer
      mov P1,A             ;Now enable only the correct soundcard
      setb ENXMIT          ;Enable data transmission
      tx2:
              mov A,@R0         ;Load a byte from our data space

              ;This fragment executes 8x but I only showed it one time here.
              ;I avoided loops. DJNZ requires two clock cycles (7uS) to process command.

              clr FLUSH                ;Enable data input **
              setb GLOBALDAT           ;Set data to high impedance so input can be captured **
              clr GLOBALCLK            ;Lower clock line to accept bit input **
              mov C,GLOBALDAT          ;Get incoming bit
              setb FLUSH               ;Disable data input
              rrc A                    ;store incoming bit and load next output bit
              mov GLOBALDAT,C          ;set data line to bit
              setb GLOBALCLK           ;raise clock so soundcard accepts bit

              ;end of repeating fragment

              mov @R0,A                ;save what soundcard sent us to our data space
              inc R0                   ;increment pointer

        djnz R7,tx2                    ;Keep going until all bytes are processed

        clr ENXMIT                     ;Disable further transmissions    
        setb GLOBALDAT                 ;Set data line to high
        mov P1,R6                      ;reset the SS line to tell soundcard we're done.

        ;Save audio statuses to RAM
        mov AUDSTATL,BUFOUT
        mov AUDSTAT,BUFOUT+2
  ret
```

As you can see, the data line (RXD) from the microcontroller is shared across every data line in the system through multiplexers/demultiplexers. This means that I need to make the line only unidirectional (not bi-directional) by enabling reception and transmitting nothing when I want to receive data.

I called the receive enable "FLUSH" because it also flushes other output lines which are out of the scope of this question.

Now what I want to try to do is make this code fragment execute much faster.

So I'm looking at these lines:

```
              clr FLUSH                ;Enable data input **
              setb GLOBALDAT           ;Set data to high impedance so input can be captured **
              clr GLOBALCLK            ;Lower clock line to accept bit input **
```

and thought instead of consecutive clear and setb statements on individual pins on the same port, I could use ANL or ORL but then if I did it direct on the port, the result might not update correctly due to the behaviour of the 8051.

Is there any other way I can modify the repetitive code to make the thing run faster?

I already did save at least 380 microseconds (6.5 microseconds per removal of DJNZ multiplied by the usage of it 8 times for a byte + 1 to load counter variable for DJNZ + other commands in loop then multiplied by bytes to process command (7 bytes))

But I want to save more than that.

Any ideas?

Except that I don't plan to remove the outer loop because doing that will increase the need for rom space substantially more and I don't have too much free rom space left.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use two different port pins for `FLUSH` and `ENXMIT`. By doing so, you can go for ANL or ORL on the port directly.